# apple one page scroller not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, scroll

I am trying to get this effect working on my rails app, but It wont work.

this is the effect that I want 
[Apple one page scroll](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/09/18/onepagescroll-js-creating-an-apples-iphone-5s-website/)

I did add the file jquery.onepage-scroll.js in the js folder in the assets folder

and then I added the file onepage-scroll.css in the stylesheets folder.

Then I added the code in my index page

```
<div class="main">
  <section>...</section>
  <section>...</section>
</div>
```

then I added the code

```
$(".main").onepage_scroll();
```

in the application.js

but it wont work and I wounder what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong, that's why it's not working... in order to make this work you'll have to add `<section></section>` as well to your code as mentioned in the example on the link you provided!
 **[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/wjgm7fnL/)**:

```
<div class="main">
    <section class="n1 section">...</section>
    <section class="n2 section">...</section>
</div>
```

and this will be your js:

```
$(".main").onepage_scroll({
    sectionContainer: "section"
});
```

Comment: hi chun, thanks for the fast answer, but it still does not work =/. I must have done something wrong here